# How to get output from class after input all values

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.title("First Software")
app.minsize(500, 500)

#For Input Declaration
UserName = StringVar()
pass1 = IntVar()

class Functions:
    def username(self, UserName):
        self.UserName = Username
        print(UserName.get())
    def password(self, pass1):
        self.pass1 = pass1
        print(pass1.get())

#---Label---
label = Label(text='Enter any Number between 1 and 100...').pack()

#---Entry---
entry = Entry(app, textvariable=UserName).pack()
entry1 = Entry(app, textvariable=pass1).pack()

#---Buttton---
button = Button(text='Submit', command=Functions).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

After running this code, How can I get separate input of Username and password by using this method. I'm lil bit confused right now!

Comment: You will have to create two input fields for them

Comment: @ThatBird The OP _has_ created 2 Entry widgets to receive the inputs.

Comment: Oh yes OP has indeed created them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command=Functions` tells Tkinter to create an instance of your `Functions` class when the Submit button is pressed. But it doesn't tell it to call the functions defined inside `Functions`. However, that class definition is a bit odd, and you don't really need a class to contain those functions. Instead, we can write a simple function that gets the values of `UserName` and `pass1` and prints them.

I've made a few other minor changes to your code.

```
import tkinter as tk

app = tk.Tk()
app.title("First Software")
#app.minsize(500, 500)

#For Input Declaration
UserName = tk.StringVar()
pass1 = tk.IntVar()

def print_entries():
    print('User name:', UserName.get())
    print('Password:', pass1.get())

tk.Label(app, text='User name.').pack()
entry = tk.Entry(app, textvariable=UserName)
entry.pack()

tk.Label(app, text='Password\nEnter any Number between 1 and 100').pack()
entry1 = tk.Entry(app, textvariable=pass1)
entry1.pack()

tk.Button(app, text='Submit', command=print_entries).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

This code doesn't actually need the names `entry` and `entry1`, but I kept them in case you want to add code that does need to refer to those widgets by name.

Note that you should *not* do

```
entry = Entry(app, textvariable=UserName).pack()
```

The `.pack` method returns `None`, so the above statement assigns the value of `None` to `entry`. Instead, we do

```
entry = tk.Entry(app, textvariable=UserName)
entry.pack()
```

That assigns the new Entry widget to the name `entry` and then calls its `.pack` method to pack it into the window.

---

If you like, you can wrap that code up in a class, but I wouldn't bother with a simple GUI like this. But this is one way to do it:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        root = tk.Tk()
        root.title("First Software")
        #root.minsize(500, 500)

        #For Input Declaration
        self.UserName = tk.StringVar()
        self.pass1 = tk.IntVar()

        tk.Label(root, text='User name.').pack()
        entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.UserName)
        entry.pack()

        tk.Label(root, text='Password\nEnter any Number between 1 and 100').pack()
        entry1 = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=self.pass1)
        entry1.pack()

        tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=self.print_entries).pack()

        root.mainloop()

    def print_entries(self):
        print('User name:', self.UserName.get())
        print('Password:', self.pass1.get())

App()
```